# Retrieving User entered data using JSON in MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

Currently am very new to ASP .NET MVC 3 and doing final year project based on it. Kindly assist for the following:

The intent is to send data entered by the user in various rows as JSON to the controller and then retrieve the values there for processing and return the success message back.

The data can be said as entered by the user in each row (there can be various rows which can dynamically be added by the user.)

To summarize, kindly assist in following two things (for ASP.NET MVC 3) :

How to convert (correctly) the user entered data into JSON for unknown number of rows.
   How to send the data and receive as a array/List of object with each Array/list object containing the data from the single row of the Interface..

The UI can be said roughly as follows:

Name    Description     Size     Date

--      ------         ---       ---
   --      -----          ---       ---

```
  **Add Row Btn**
```

Kind regards,
A.Ali

Comment: This is basically what MVC3 is all in all. You should really do a tutorial as you need more information than one StackOverflow answer

Answer (score 1):

Model

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "My Field")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public String myField { get;set; }
}
```

View

```
@Model namespace.MyModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <h1>Edit Fields</h1>
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.myField 
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.myField)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.myField)
}
```

Controller

```
public class Home : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
    {
        // do stuff
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the time. but if appropriate, kindly assist with the jquery/javascript code for sending array of dynamically entered rows as JSON and mapping each row's data as an object in the controller.  apologies if question seems inappropriate.

Comment: I agree with Mike. The data you are sending to your controller, will be binded to your model. Can you show us some example code so we can move you in the right direction.